# Access object from script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing java script code in script tag in head like:

```
 <head>
     <script language="javascript">
         object o = new object({....});
     </script>
 </head>
```

and trying to use object a in body tag

```
<body>
    <script>
         alert(o.value);
    </script>
</body>
```

how can i access object from body???
is their any alternatives?

Comment: your var a its available by all page, head and body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <head>
    <script language="javascript">
         var o = new Object();
         o.value="a"
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() 
     {
        alert(o.value)
    });
    </script>       
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `var a` is accessible in complete application, but one thing you need to make sure if you are using external JS files then it must be loaded when you using the variable. try onload function to assure JS is loaded and ready to use in body:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
  alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable is declared outside any functions it can be accessed from anywhere in your document from the same script block or from a seperate script block like in your example. it can even be accessed from html event-attributes like this (note that its better to attach events to html elements using using js):

```
<button onclick="alert(a);">Click this button to open an alert!</button>
```